# Got stuck on this error while coding in flutter: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]

Tags: flutter, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

This error rises every time i try to run a firebaseAuth command:
for example - the main two commands i ran were:
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
or
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword
the full error i got in the debug console was:

> I/FirebaseAuth(16987): Logging in as t@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  (16987): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> W/LocalRequestInterceptor(16987): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
> D/EGL_emulation(16987): app_time_stats: avg=9597.83ms min=9597.83ms max=9597.83ms count=1
> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(16987): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]
> E/flutter (16987): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.

Initially i thought that the problem was originated from a bad\faulty connection with firebase, but after a couple of checks i found out it wasn't the case.
i also have to mention i worked on a whole bunch of projects before this one, and everything worked just fine.. i guess it maybe has something to do with the fact that the file im currently working on wasn't originated from my pc, but instead it is a git-clone of a project my prof sent us.

i have been trying to fix this issue for two weeks now and had no success, i hope someone is familiar with this happening and i would be glad to receive help.
thanks in advance!